# VBA macro for Excel, having an array as input and an array as output

Tags: excel, vba

I want to write a VBA function which takes an array as input from an Excel worksheet and puts a modified array as output to another range on the same worksheet.

My arrays have typically 20 numbers and there are going to be lots of such calls on the same worksheet. I tried a simple example with a single 2x3 matrix and failed. Getting the input into VBA works fine, but I could not put the output from the function back to Excel. With a stand-alone subroutine I encounter no problem.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const nR As Long = 3
Private Const nC As Long = 2

Public MsgTxt As String
Public MsgTit As String
Public iMsg As Integer

Private ArrO(1 To nR, 1 To nC) As Variant

Function DoArrays(wrF As Range, wrT As Range) As Long
    Dim nRI As Long
    Dim nCI As Long
    Dim iR As Long
    Dim iC As Long
    Dim wc1 As Range
    Dim wcx As Range

    Dim ArrI() As Variant
    ArrI = wrF.Value

    nRI = wrF.Rows.Count
    If nRI <> nR Then
        MsgTit = "GetArray: misaligned rows"
        MsgTxt = "nRI = " & CStr(nRI)
        iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbCritical, MsgTit)
        End
    End If

    nCI = wrF.Columns.Count
    If nCI <> nC Then
        MsgTit = "GetArray: misaligned columns"
        MsgTxt = "nCI = " & CStr(nCI)
        iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbCritical, MsgTit)
        End
    End If

    For iR = 1 To nR
        For iC = 1 To nC
            ArrO(iC, iR) = -ArrI(iR, iC)
        Next iC
    Next iR

    Set wc1 = wrF.Cells(1, 1)
    Set wcx = wrF.Cells(nR, nC)

    MsgTit = "DoArrays"
    MsgTxt = ""
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "Range wrF"
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "# rows = " & CStr(nR)
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "# cols = " & CStr(nC)
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "address of first cell = " & wc1.Address
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "address of last  cell = " & wcx.Address
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "Array Arr"
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & " 1st index runs " & CStr(LBound(ArrI, 1)) & " to " & CStr(UBound(ArrI, 1))
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & " 2nd index runs " & CStr(LBound(ArrI, 2)) & " to " & CStr(UBound(ArrI, 2))
    iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbInformation, MsgTit)

    Call PutArray(wrT)

    DoArrays = nR * nC
End Function

Sub PutArray(wrT As Range)
    Dim nRT As Long
    Dim nCT As Long

    nRT = wrT.Rows.Count
    If nRT <> nC Then
        MsgTit = "PutArray: misaligned rows"
        MsgTxt = "nRT = " & CStr(nRT)
        iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbCritical, MsgTit)
        End
    End If

    nCT = wrT.Columns.Count
    If nCT <> nR Then
        MsgTit = "PutArray: misaligned columns"
        MsgTxt = "nCT = " & CStr(nCT)
        iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbCritical, MsgTit)
        End
    End If

    MsgTit = "Range wrT in Putarray"
    MsgTxt = ""
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "Range wrT"
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "# rows = " & CStr(nR)
    MsgTxt = MsgTxt & vbCrLf & "# cols = " & CStr(nC)
    iMsg = MsgBox(MsgTxt, vbInformation, MsgTit)

    wrT.Value = ArrO
End Sub

Sub main2()
    Dim wr As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ArrO(1, 1) = 11
    ArrO(1, 2) = 21
    ArrO(1, 3) = 31
    ArrO(2, 1) = 12
    ArrO(2, 2) = 22
    ArrO(2, 3) = 32

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    Set wr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(9, 2), ws.Cells(10, 4))

    Call PutArray(wr)
End Sub
```

The function DoArrays works fine all the way to the very last statment in the subroutine PutArray. Ther it fails and returns with #VALUE.  The same subroutine PutArray works fine if it is called in 'stand-alone' manner from the sub Main2.

I suspect the issue here is the ability of Excel to detect circular references. But there must be a soultion. The built-in function MINV is providing exactly the functionality I want. Is there a way to use the magic CSE key strokes (control shift enter) in connection with a VBA macro?

Comment: Don't understand how any of it can work as `ArrO` is 3x2 but in main2 it is being defined as 2x3?

Comment: How are you calling `DoArrays`? I ask as I think you might be calling it as a UDF on the sheet itself? If so, you should know that UDFs can't (yes, there are rare exceptions) generally alter cells on the worksheet, other than the cell that's calling the UDF.

Comment: I'm not seeing the circular reference that you're encountering. When I tried to run your code, I encountered a few blocking problems such as the array dimension mismatch that @SJR noted above plus your comparisons `nRT <> nC` and `nCT <> nR` I think are incorrect. (should be `nRT <> nR` and `nCT <> nC`?) I can't be sure because you haven't defined the size of your "to" array and what transform you're making on the "from" array.

Comment: If you are using this function on the worksheet, to return the individual values, either embed it into the `INDEX` function, and change the row/column indices as you fill the formula down and right, or enter it as an array over a range of cells large enough to encompass the results.

Comment: @CLR: Thanks, you confirm what I suspected as explanation of my small test.

Comment: @Ron: I tried your proposal with a range of cells large enough. But I could not get it working. But you motivated me to dig further. Finally I found a solution, which works for me. It is described in my next comment below.

Comment: My function now accepts two ranges as input, each containing the data of a state vector. The calculations of the function generate a matrix.This matrix, which is declared as array of variant is assigned to the result of the function.On the worksheet I arrange the first state vector, the matrix and the second state vector nicely next to each other. The first cell of the matrix contains the function call, which is extended to the entire range with the CSE keystrokes. This works nicely. Althog 9 cells are computed, the function is evaluated only once.